# save image file to local system in java desktop application

Tags: java

I want to save an image file which is chosen by JFileChooser.The file should be saved to my local sysytem in java desktop application.  How it is possible?? Please help me to do this thing..
I am using the following code to choose the image file

```
public static String Filechooser(Component parent)
    {
        JFileChooser fcProductImage = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = fcProductImage.showOpenDialog(parent);

    if (returnVal == fcProductImage.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    {
        java.io.File file = fcProductImage.getSelectedFile();
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } 
    else 
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: So what have you tried ?

Comment: How is the file represented in your application?

Comment: Where is the file coming *from*?

Comment: You're not telling us what you've tried, how it's not working, or what you don't understand. Please improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ImageIO.write(image,extension,file);`

**See the Snippet of Code below:**

```
JFileChooser FC=new JFileChooser("C:/");
FC.addChoosableFileFilter(new jpgSaveFilter());
FC.addChoosableFileFilter(new jpegSaveFilter());
FC.addChoosableFileFilter(new PngSaveFilter());
FC.addChoosableFileFilter(new gifSaveFilter());
FC.addChoosableFileFilter(new BMPSaveFilter());
FC.addChoosableFileFilter(new wbmpSaveFilter()); 

int retrival=m_fileChooser_save.showSaveDialog(null);

if (retrival == m_fileChooser_save.APPROVE_OPTION) 
   {

        String ext="";

        String extension=m_fileChooser_save.getFileFilter().getDescription();

       if(extension.equals("*.jpg,*.JPG"))
      { 
          ext=".jpg";
      }
      if(extension.equals("*.png,*.PNG"))
      { 
          ext=".png";
      }
      if(Extension.equals("*.gif,*.GIF"))
      { 
          ext=".gif";
      }
      if(extension.equals("*.wbmp,*.WBMP"))
      { 
          ext=".wbmp";
      }
      if(Extension.equals("*.jpeg,*.JPEG"))
      { 
          EXT=".jpeg";
      }
      if(extension.equals("*.bmp,*.BMP"))
      { 
          ext=".bmp";
      }
```

**Example Filter:**

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;   
 class jpgSaveFilter extends FileFilter
 { 
    public boolean accept(File f)
   {
        if (f.isDirectory())
          {
            return false;
          }

         String s = f.getName();

        return s.endsWith(".jpg")||s.endsWith(".JPG");
   }

   public String getDescription() 
  {
       return "*.jpg,*.JPG";
  }

}
```